# Stop Vis.js network spinning

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

I have a network that can have 0 or more base nodes, with 0 or more nodes interconnected to them. The problem is that when I have nodes that are connected off the side, this seems to be causing velocity in that direction which in turn causes the network to spin.

How can I stop this spinning? It's not as simple as adding nodes to the other side because of the way that the network renders the nodes.

Gif below shows the nodes that hang off to the sides that cause the spinning (**ignore the red nodes, they are not relevant to the issue**).The network will spin in the opposite direction of these nodes.

[image: Spinning nodes]

Vis.js options:

```
var options = {
interaction: {
  hover: true
},
physics: {
    forceAtlas2Based: {
      gravitationalConstant: -50,
      springLength: 100,
      avoidOverlap: 1,
      damping: 1
    },
    minVelocity: 0.75,
    solver: 'forceAtlas2Based'
}
```

Comment: Why do you need gravity simulation for network vizualization?

Comment: @Andrey Are you referring to the "gravitational constant" in the options? If so, this is required for pulling the nodes closer (or pushing them apart). When I remove this the issue still occurs

Comment: I meant me not understanding usage of physics for such a simple things. Anyways, have you tried `stabilization` option in physics?

Comment: @Andrey nodes are dynamically added and removed at any point during the user viewing the network. When physics is enabled and this happens, not going to lie - it looks cool :) 
I have tried stabilization, unfortunately any changes I make to those options don't help. Also `network.stabilize()` can't solve the spinning as it does not redraw the nodes (on the other side for example). Perhaps it's the solver I'm using

Answer (score 1):

try `damping > 1`

I know docs say accepted range for damping is 0..1, but I was desperate enough to try anything.

I ended up using 2.5 but you can go much higher.

Comment: This saved me from going insane.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once the network loads you can use setoption physics as false.

network.setOptions( { physics: false } );